# Equations of constrained motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

When we solve  a mechanics problem, we do it by forming constrained motion equations and at times we write the same equations again, is there any way to identify which all equations are  unique and not just a manipulation of what we wrote previously?

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: -1. Unclear. Please provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to answer your question from what little context you have supplied.For example, if you are working with pulleys, you can skip adding the equations of two pulleys which have a COMMON point( say another pulley above them); for it will be redundant with the equation obtained for THAT COMMON POINT DIRECTLY. Same goes for Kirchhoff's laws. There is no point adding the loop equations for 2 adjacent loops, for we can directly obtain the loop equation along the perimeter of the combined loop; which will be the same as the sum of split equations.

The point is, it is only what you might call 'common sense' or 'presence of mind' that allows to identify which equation might be redundant. Of course, practice helps. But if you REALLY want an 'algorithm'( so to speak), the equations describing motion of 2 bodies having a common 'link' (whatever that might be) are redundant with the equation of the link itself. (Think of it this way-the common 'link' IS the reason for the constrained relationship, isn't it?).

NOTE- the use of the word 'link' is rather vague here, but without any solid context, that's the best I could do.

Hope this helps.